# React Native and Expo - Update multiple apps with the same foundation

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a question about updating multiple apps using expo.  In the scenario where the app is provided to several different customers, then each one has their own version of the same app, where they only change color and logo settings.  (as they do nowadays in virtual stores).
In this case the visual settings that are changed are received from a server.  But when the app receives a general update, all clients should receive the same update.
To do this for dozens of customers will be a very counterproductive process, especially when the customer base grows.
Is there any way to automate this?  So that I run the EAS update of the main project and all apps from dozens of clients receive this update?
Remembering that it is not that several customers connect to a main app and only enter their login data.  It's something like your own virtual store where each customer pays to use a customized version and has its link in your android and apple store.  Thanks for the help.

So far, the only available way I see would be to manually update each client, changing only the json data that references the app